# Optimization array operations

Tags: c#, arrays, list, optimization

I have task to optimize amount of iterations over array.

I have such source array:

```
int[] dataArray = new int[10] {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
```

Where 0-no feature, 1 - feature present.
This

```
public struct MyDataStruct
{
    public int Index; //index in array
    public int Value; //some value
}
```

There are also two ways of reprezentation of some feature: ideally I need to use ONLY OptimizedKeyValueArray1 and to remove all usings of NotOptimizedKeyValueArray1.

```
public static readonly MyDataStruct[] NotOptimizedKeyValueArray1 =
        {
                new MyDataStruct(0, -1),
                new MyDataStruct(1, 1000),
                new MyDataStruct(2, 2500),
                new MyDataStruct(3, 4500),
                new MyDataStruct(4, -1),
                new MyDataStruct(5, -1),
                new MyDataStruct(6, -1),
                new MyDataStruct(7, -1),
                new MyDataStruct(8, 6500),
                new MyDataStruct(9, -1)
        };

public static readonly MyDataStruct[] OptimizedKeyValueArray1 =
        {
                new MyDataStruct(1, 1000),
                new MyDataStruct(2, 2500),
                new MyDataStruct(3, 4500),
                new MyDataStruct(8, 6500)
        };
```

As a result I need to have resultArray, the same quantity as inputArray:

```
int[] inputArray = new int[10] {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};

MyDataStruct[] resultDataSet = new MyDataStruct[10];
```

This is my solution of this task, but it is not optimized and not scalable, because I am iterate over the elements which are not important for me and I know about it from the very begining. As result I have 10 elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
{
    resultDataSet[i] = new MyDataStruct(i, dataArray[i]);
}
```

But SOMEHOW I need to make it more efficient and NOT iterate over the 0-value elements. But according this code, I will create only 4 elements, while I need to have other 6 elements with some default values. And I don't know how to do it more efficiently.

```
for(int i = 0; i < OptimizedKeyValueArray1.Length; i++)
{
    int index = OptimizedKeyValueArray1.Index;
    int value = OptimizedKeyValueArray1.Value;

    resultDataSet[i] = new MyDataStruct(i, dataArray[i]);
}
```

Or maybe you can propose some more efficient algorithms over the array to do this task. Thanks.

Comment: use this linq statement  int[] inputArray2= inputArray.Where(item => item == 1).ToArray(); to get only four items as per requirement and then run loop on it

Comment: No linq, I can't use it.

Comment: Is this homework? If you want to iteratate only over the enabled values you should sort the array by the featureflag. Then your can iterate over the array until you hit a disabled feature which is a simple end condition.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you mean, a bit unclear if you want to use the NotOptimized array or just the Optimized one, this is how I'd do it if you can take the elements from the 1st array:

```
const int arraySize = 10;

//No need int[] if only 0 & 1   
bool[] dataArray = new bool[arraySize] {false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, true, false};

List<MyDataStruct> resultDataSet = new List<MyDataStruct> ();
//You must iterate on all dataArray, no real way around it
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (dataArray[i])
      resultDataSet.Add(NotOptimizedKeyValueArray1[i]);
}
```

If you must have same number of elements then you should use another array:

```
MyDataStruct[] resultDataSet = new MyDataStruct[arraySize];
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (dataArray[i])
      resultDataSet[i] = NotOptimizedKeyValueArray1[i];
    else
      resultDataSet[i] = new MyDataStruct(); //whatever your default is.
}
```

Comment: But in such way I will get only 4 elements in my resultDataSet with values. And I need to have all 10, but 6 of them must be with some default values.

Comment: Ive edited my anser @yozhik